# Texto que desliza ao passar o mouse

Tags: jquery, html

Tenho esse código `marquee` aqui:

```
<marquee direction="left" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();" scrollamount="2" height='18px' width='180px'>MEU TEXTO</marquee>
```

Gostaria que o texto rolasse APENAS quando eu passasse o mouse por cima e parasse quando eu tirasse o mouse de cima.

Não queria usar essa "MARQUEE" mais sim um jQuery pra ficar algo mais elegante.

---

adaptei porém não funcionou: http://jsfiddle.net/56pb9nwp/

O está rolando sozinho!

Answer (score 1):

Da para utilizar o [Jquery Marquee](http://aamirafridi.com/jquery/jquery-marquee-plugin)

Adaptando somente a sua necessidade.

```
var $mq = $('.marquee').marquee();

//Pause
$('.p').click(function(){
  $mq.marquee('pause');
});

//Resume
$('.r').click(function(){
  $mq.marquee('resume');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um plugin do jQuery no caso, existem várias opções.

> site projeto: http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee
>
> exemplo online: http://download.remysharp.com/marquee.html

Comment: Certo, mais nenhum dos efeitos faz o que preciso, poderia me indicar alguma modificação no código que tenho? Ficaria mais fácil pois sou meio leigo no assunto.